# Can a list have more than one lists in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

i am trying to retrieve records from the db for three different columns. I need a way to store the data from these columns so that i am able to iterate through the first column and put some checks on the data from the other two columns. the first thing i was trying was to have three different list and each list having records from those three columns simultaneously but that way i wont be able to return all the three lists from a single method, I need all those data retrieved from the db and then i am gona use it in another class. Is there a way a list can have more than one lists inside of it. Is there any other solution for this problem, an other suggestions. 
thanks.

Comment: Did you try writing a class for your data?

Comment: i am working in a huge application, we have separate classes for DAO(retrieve data from database) and business logic.. I can just write  methods in the existing classes.

Comment: can you please post what you have written till now?

Comment: Well, Java will let you have a `List<List<?>>` but it's almost certainly the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a bean (Say DbResult) with three fields column1, column2 and column3.
Then create and return a list of DbResult: `List<DbResult> resultList = new ArrayList<DbResult>();`

This way you can pass all your data to the caller method;

Review DTO patern [DTO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/transferobject-139757.html)

Answer (score 3):

In java you would declare a class with three fields. For example like this:

```
public class Person {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String birthName;
}
```

(if you prefer, you can also use getter and setter methods)

You can then store instances of that class in a list:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
Person person = new Person()
person.firstName = "Mario"
...
persons.add(person);
```

If you are not allowed to create new Java-files (for whatever reason...), than you can even include the Person class inside of another class or interface:

```
public class ExistingClass {
    public static class Person {
        ...
    }

    ...the rest of the the existing class...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class which ll hold a row's data from the tabel.

Like :

```
Class Row {
    int column1;
    int column2;
    int column3;
}
```

And then you should create a list of this class objects like : `List<Row>`.

In this way you can iterate through one list and access all column values and you can also return the list in any function.